# Update text dynamically in Bokeh with js_on_change

Tags: python, bokeh, bokehjs

Is it possible to use `js_on_change` with `bokeh` to dynamically update text that is placed next to a plot?

For example, using this code snippet from a different question

```py
from random import random
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Span
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("callback.html")

x = [random() for x in range(500)]
y = [random() for y in range(500)]
color = ["navy"] * len(x)

s = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, color=color))
p = figure(plot_width=400,
           plot_height=400,
           tools="lasso_select",
           title="Select Here")
p.circle(x='x', y='y', color='color', size=8, source=s, alpha=0.4)

slope = Span(location=.5,
             dimension="width",
             line_alpha=.6,
             line_width=5)
p.add_layout(slope)

s.selected.js_on_change(
    'indices',
    CustomJS(args=dict(s=s, slope=slope),
             code="""       
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        
        if (inds.length == 0) {
            slope.location = 0.5
            return 
        }
        
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            total += s.data["y"][inds[i]]
        }
        var avg = total / inds.length;
        slope.location = avg;
    """))

show(p)
```

I'd like to include a text right of the figure that shows the value of the computed `slope.location` and updates whenever I select new points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use a Text Widget like `PreText`, place it on the right side of the plot [e.g via `layout`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html) and update the `.text` property of that widget in your JSCallback. Make sure you use the `.toString()` methode to assign the value.

```
from random import random
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Span, PreText
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import layout

output_file("callback.html")

x = [random() for x in range(500)]
y = [random() for y in range(500)]
color = ["navy"] * len(x)

s = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, color=color))
p = figure(plot_width=400,
           plot_height=400,
           tools="lasso_select",
           title="Select Here")
p.circle(x='x', y='y', color='color', size=8, source=s, alpha=0.4)

slope = Span(location=.5,
             dimension="width",
             line_alpha=.6,
             line_width=5)
p.add_layout(slope)

slope_text = PreText(text='Slope_Text')

s.selected.js_on_change(
    'indices',
    CustomJS(args=dict(s=s, slope=slope, slope_text=slope_text),
             code="""       
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        
        if (inds.length == 0) {
            slope.location = 0.5
            return 
        }
        
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            total += s.data["y"][inds[i]]
        }
        var avg = total / inds.length;
        slope.location = avg;
        slope_text.text = avg.toString();
    """))

layout_ = layout([[p,slope_text]])
show(layout_)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried this out and it works perfectly. Would it be possible to edit your answer to include another remark on the following: What if I want to use `box_zoom` instead of `lasso_select`? How would I get the mean of the points I zoomed in on? (I know this is somewhat a new question, but maybe you know the answer, too.)

Comment: Do you want to select points via `box_select`? Therefor, you simply replace `lasso_select` with `box_select`. Or do you really want to calculate the average of exactly those points shown in the plot, after zooming in with `box_zoom`?

Comment: No, not via `box_select`, but via zooming in with `box zoom` and "selecting" those points inside the zoom region. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it does. However, I don't think there is a built-in way to select only visible samples. What you could do is iterating over all samples in your `ColumnDataSource` and check if `x` and `y` values are within your visible ranges. Eg. check if `p.x_range.start < x < p.x_range.end` is True. (Same needs to be done for your y-values). If both conditions are met, store those indices and then calculate the average you need only of those samples.